# Azure Webjob, KeyVault Configuration extension, Socket Error

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-keyvault

Need some help to determine if this is a bug in my code or in the config kevault extensions.

I have a netcore console based webjob.  all working fine until a few weeks ago when we stated getting occasional startup errors which were Socket Error 10060 - Socket timed out or "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

These were all related to loading configuration layers (app settings, env, command line and keyvault).  The errors stemmed from the keyvault once the build was executed on the hostbuilder.

I initially added the retry policy with the default HttpStatusCodeErrorDetectionStrategy and an exponential back-off but this is not executing.

finally I added my own retry policy with my own detection strategy (see below).  Still not being fired.

I have stripped down the code to a hello world like example and included the messages from the webjob.

Here is the code summary:

**Main**

```
    public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args)
            .UseConsoleLifetime()
            .Build();

        using var serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope();

        var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

        //**stripped down to logging just for debug

        var loggerFactory = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Main");

        logger.LogDebug("Hello Test App Started OK.  Exiting.");

        //**Normally lots of service calls go here to do real work**

        return 0;
    }
```

**HostBuilder** - why hostbuilder?  We use lots of components that are built for webapi and webapps so it was convenient to use a similar services model.

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var host = Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, config) =>
            {
                //override with keyvault
                var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();   //this is awesome - it will use MSI or Visual Studio connection

                var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

                var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<ServerErrorDetectionStrategy>(
                        new ExponentialBackoffRetryStrategy(
                            retryCount: 5,
                            minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0),
                            maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16.0),
                            deltaBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0)
                            )
                        );

                retryPolicy.Retrying += RetryPolicy_Retrying;

                keyVaultClient.SetRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);


                var prebuiltConfig = config.Build();

                config.AddAzureKeyVault(prebuiltConfig.GetSection("KeyVaultSettings").GetValue<string>("KeyVaultUri"), keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());

                config.AddCommandLine(args);

            })
            .ConfigureLogging((ctx, loggingBuilder) =>  //note - this is run AFTER app configuration - whatever the order it is in.
            {
                loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();

                loggingBuilder
                    .AddConsole()
                    .AddDebug()
                    .AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(config => config.InstrumentationKey = ctx.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"]);

            })
            .ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
            {
                services
                    .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

                services
                    .AddOptions();


            });
        return host;
    }
```

**Event** - this is never fired.

```
    private static void RetryPolicy_Retrying(object sender, RetryingEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Retrying, count = {e.CurrentRetryCount}, Last Exception={e.LastException}, Delay={e.Delay}");
    }
```

**Retry Policy** - only fires for the non-MSI attempt to contact the keyvault.

```
public class ServerErrorDetectionStrategy : ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy
{
    public bool IsTransient(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception {ex.Message} received, {ex.GetType()?.FullName}");
            HttpRequestWithStatusException httpException;
            if ((httpException = ex as HttpRequestWithStatusException) != null)
            {
                switch(httpException.StatusCode)
                {
                    case HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout:
                    case HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout:
                    case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                    case HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable:
                        return true;
                }
            }

            SocketException socketException;
            if((socketException = (ex as SocketException)) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception {socketException.Message} received, Error Code: {socketException.ErrorCode}, SocketErrorCode: {socketException.SocketErrorCode}");

                if (socketException.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**WebJob Output**

```
[SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[SYS INFO] Run script 'run.cmd' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[INFO] 
[INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\HelloWebJob\42wj5ipx.ukj>dotnet HelloWebJob.dll  
[INFO] Exception Response status code indicates server error: 401 (Unauthorized). received,     Microsoft.Rest.TransientFaultHandling.HttpRequestWithStatusException
[INFO] Exception A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. received, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
[ERR ] Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
[ERR ]  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
[ERR ]    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[ERR ]    at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[ERR ]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
[ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync(String vaultBaseUrl, String secretName, String secretVersion, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretAsync(IKeyVaultClient operations, String secretIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[ERR ]    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync()
[ERR ]    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load()
[ERR ]    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
[ERR ]    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
[ERR ]    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
[ERR ]    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
[ERR ]    at HelloWebJob.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\mark\Source\Repos\HelloWebJob\HelloWebJob\Program.cs:line 21
[ERR ]    at HelloWebJob.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
[SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
```

Comment: note - investigating this https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/6003#issuecomment-510562482 as it may be the AzureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback that is causing the prob.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in the KV connectivity which is identified by the PG. Below is an official statement from Product Group:

> The Microsoft Azure App Service Team has identified an issue with the
> Key Vault references for App Service and Azure Functions feature
> related to intermittent failure to resolve references at runtime.
>
> Engineers identified a regression in the system that reduced the
> performance and availability of our scale unit’s ability to retrieve
> key vault references at runtime. A patch has been written and deployed
> to our fleet of VMs to mitigate this issue.
>
> We are continuously taking steps to improve the Azure Web App service
> and our processes to ensure such incidents do not occur in the future,
> and in this case, it includes (but is not limited to): Improving
> detection and testing of performance and availability of the Key Vault
> App Setting References feature Improvements to our platform to ensure
> high availability of this feature at runtime. We apologize for any
> inconvenience.

**For almost everyone, updating packages to the new `Microsoft.Azure` packages has mitigated this issue, so trying those would be my first suggestion.**

Comment: Thanks - I posted a work around in the interim (very basic retry on the host builder).  Will investigate the msft.azure nugets now.

Comment: Update:  We are using IConfiguration.AddAzureKeyVault(...) which looks like it is only in the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault namespace.  We use the options pattern to ensure only settings needed are provided to dependencies vs the entire config or reading each one at time of use.  I did not see an equivalent for the new azure SDK.  LMK if there is one.

Comment: Can you upgrade it's version to 3.1.8 and let me know if it works.

Comment: confirmed - 3.1.8.

Comment: If I use my main() retry (as above), it works but I am still getting connection errors to the KV which recover by using that retry.

Comment: Okay, then I suppose the issue is resolved for now. Try using different KV sdk with caching implemented, it will also serve your purpose.

Comment: Do any of the updated KV SDKs implement IConfiguration.AddAzureKeyvault? I understand how you can get the secrets directly using the new SDK but that binds the class to an implementation.  In our system, we are injecting subsections of configuration using IOptions pattern.  The backing for that is IConfiguration and we add each layer of config source (app settings, appsettings.dev, env, and KeyVault using this extension.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.azurekeyvaultconfigurationextensions.addazurekeyvault?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1?

Comment: yes it did and that is how we have moved forward.  I was wondering if there was a new Azure.* configuration extension for IConfiguration that added keyvault as a provider and therefore might use the new SDK or if this will continue to live in Microsoft.Configuration.Extensions and reference the old keyvault sdk libraries (and hence still need to do our own transient fault handling).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @HarshitaSingh-MSFT, makes sense though I searched for this when I had the problem and couldn't find it.

As a work around, I added some basic retry code to the startup.

Main looks like this for now:

```
    public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = null;
        int retries = 5;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Building Host...");
                var hostBuilder = CreateHostBuilder(args)
                    .UseConsoleLifetime();

                host = hostBuilder.Build();

                break;
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException hEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"HTTP Exception in host builder. {hEx.Message}, Name:{hEx.GetType().Name}");

                SocketException se;

                if ((se = hEx.InnerException as SocketException) != null)
                {
                    if (se.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Socket error in host builder.  Retrying...");

                        if (retries > 0)
                        {
                            retries--;

                            await Task.Delay(5000);

                            host?.Dispose();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        using var serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope();

        var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

        var transferService = services.GetRequiredService<IRunPinTransfer>();

        var result = await transferService.ProcessAsync();

        return result;

    }
```